# how can i append a list item

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, append

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href=""><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></a></li>");
```

This is giving me an error on my console it says 
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: `href=""` closes the string, causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `""` of the `href` to `''` otherwise they close your string. Here is a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul").append("<li><a href=''><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></a></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but i cant seem to display the php code session i included

Comment: @Lestah since jQuery is client side, I don't think you can invoke PHP like so, I would suggest trying a different approach, although my answer fixes your issue, maybe ask a different question? Since this solved your problem may I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors can solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would write it this way

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href=\" \"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></a></li>");
```

or this way

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href=''><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></a></li>");
```